# Using a Synchronized collection between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

Code -> http://pastebin.com/1PFCGWQy

Blocks that I'm having problems with

```
class ClientSender implements Runnable {
        Socket server;
        ServerClientFrontEnd SCFE;
        public ClientSender(Socket server, ServerClientFrontEnd SCFE){
            this.server = server;
            this.SCFE = SCFE;
        }

        public void run(){
            try(ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream())){
                //System.out.println("Client chat ver. 0.1");
                //Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
                while(!server.isClosed()){
                    //System.out.print("YOU:");
                    if(!SCFE.synchronizedOutputCollection.isEmpty()) // Here
                    {
                        logger.info("Has made it to ClientSender!");
                        String string = SCFE.synchronizedOutputCollection.firstElement();
                        logger.info(string);
                        out.writeObject(string); // Here
                        logger.info("Output Queue: " + SCFE.synchronizedOutputCollection.toString());
                    }
                    //else{ logger.info("It failed the conditional"); }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //logger.info("Closing connection...");
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    class ClientReceiver implements Runnable {
        Socket server;
        ServerClientFrontEnd SCFE;
        public ClientReceiver(Socket server, ServerClientFrontEnd SCFE){
            this.server = server;
            this.SCFE = SCFE;
        }

        public void run(){
            try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream())){
                while(!server.isClosed()){
                    SCFE.ChatBox.setText(SCFE.ChatBox.getText() + "\nOTHER: " + (String) in.readObject()); //Here
                    logger.info("Receiver has read object!");
                }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    logger.info("Closing connection");
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

For some reason, I can not get this to work. I already got it working on a command-line environment, quite perfectly, but I wanted to port it to a graphical user interface and this problem has had me stumped for more than on hour. I didn't know how to handle the fact that Client's original class called other threads which I needed to send and receive the information to and from the server.

Basically, my program works by having the client connect to the server via a ServerSocket, which THEN processes each request. Of course, I've just recently learned about sockets on Thursday but I wanted to make a program of my own... anyway, moving on, the problem is with the ServerClientFrontEnd Class, which for some reason, and I don't know how for the life of me, the collection I'm using to get the inputted text either remains empty or it just will not read from it.

Maybe it might have to do with my while loop, but it worked perfectly before. I have a TON of loggers everywhere to log everything, and if I add an else statement when it checks if the collection is empty, it definitely activates the else statement repeatedly, EVEN AFTER the synchronizedOutputCollection was given a value. In fact, I even print the value inside of the collection when the send button is pressed. In fact, when I attempt a similar print statement inside the thread, the collection is empty and it remains empty.

How can I share a synchronized collection of objects among threads? This question is plaguing me and I would really appreciate a reply.

Also this is runnable, you just have to activate server and 2 clients to test it. P.S I have tried BlockingQueues but they make the GUI thread to freeze up because the queue is never read from, causing a deadlock.

Comment: Hmm, no.  Create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (otherwise known as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) and paste it here.  Not going to wade through your entire project looking for a logic error.

Comment: I added a code block for the two threads in question I'm having a problem with and added comments besides the Areas of Interest where a problem is occurring. I don't think I can make a SSCCE becuase it just won't work and I don't know how to get it to work even if i did trim the code.

Comment: "I can not get this to work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Your code is really goofy.  You have a client and a server, but they both share the same GUI object (the ServerClientFrontEnd).  Also you appear to be accessing your JFrame (again the ServerClientFrontEnd) from **ALL** threads, client and server.  That can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @markspace pointed out in a comment you have lots of funny things going on in your code. You should take a step backward, go back to the command line interface and rework your entire class structure. Remove those inner classes, use some interfaces like `MessageListener` or `ConnectionListnener` that your client or server uses to talk to other classes (like your GUI) about things like messages received or connection created/lost.

When you get done your client main method should look very simple:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1");
    client.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
        public void messageRecieved(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    });

    client.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected to server.");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userInput = null;
    boolean quit = false;
    do {
        userInput = scanner.readLine();
        if(userInput != null && userInput.equals("quit")) {
            client.sendMessage(userInput);
        } else {
            quit = true;
        }
    } while(!quit);
}
```

Of course I just made this up but its just an example of once you have your class structure properly broken out and things where they should be it will be very easy to hook a GUI up.

The list could go on but bottom line is you need to take a hard look at what classes need to know what information and why. Break apart classes and make fields `private` and dont share information unless they need to be shared! Its important that you really think about reducing [code coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

---

Any way enough rambling and onto the actual problem with your code: in `ServerClientFrontEnd.main` you have this snipplet:

```
new ServerClientFrontEnd().startClient();

/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new ServerClientFrontEnd().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

You are creating 2 instances of `ServerClientFrontEnd`, one that starts the client the other that shows the GUI. The one that shows the GUI is the one where you change the `List` of strings and the other list is always empty. To make it work change the snipplet to read:

```
/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ServerClientFrontEnd fontEnd = new ServerClientFrontEnd();
        fontEnd.startClient();
        fontEnd.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```